# E-Mail with plain text part, html part and attachments

Tags: perl, email, mime, html-email, email-attachments

I am trying to program a little Perl script which send plain text/html emails with attachments:

```
      use Encode();
      use MIME::Entity();
      my $msg = MIME::Entity->build(
        From        => '"' . Encode::encode( 'MIME-Header', 'Any User' ) . '" <any.user@example.test>',
        To      => '"' . Encode::encode( 'MIME-Header', 'Some User' ) . '" <some.user@example.test>',
        Subject     => Encode::encode( 'MIME-Header', 'Multipart alternative with attachments' ),
        Type        => 'multipart/alternative',
      );
      my $plain = $msg->attach(
        Type            => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        Data            => [ "*Multipart alternative with attachments*\n\nHere comes the plain text." ],
      );
      my $fancy = $msg->attach( Type => 'multipart/related' );
      $fancy->attach(
        Type            => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
        Data            => [ "<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\t<h1>Multipart alternative with attachments</h1>\n\t\t<p>Here comes the fancy text.</p>\n\t</body>\n</html>" ],
      );
      $fancy->attach(
        Type            => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        Disposition     => 'attachment',
        Filename        => 'test.txt',
        Data            => [ "*Multipart alternative with attachments*\n\nHere comes the attachment." ],
      );
```

I am getting the following MIME source code:

```
      Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----------=_1334231022-8218-0"
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
      MIME-Version: 1.0
      X-Mailer: MIME-tools 5.502 (Entity 5.502)
      From: "Any User" <any.user@example.test>
      To: "Some User" <some.user@example.test>
      Subject: Multipart alternative with attachments

      This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

      ------------=_1334231022-8218-0
      Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
      Content-Disposition: inline
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

      *Multipart alternative with attachments*

      Here comes the plain text.
      ------------=_1334231022-8218-0
      Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="----------=_1334231022-8218-1"
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

      This is a multi-part message in MIME format...

      ------------=_1334231022-8218-1
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
      Content-Disposition: inline
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

      <html>
              <body>
                      <h1>Multipart alternative with attachments</h1>
                      <p>Here comes the fancy text.</p>
              </body>
      </html>
      ------------=_1334231022-8218-1
      Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="test.txt"
      Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.txt"
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

      *Multipart alternative with attachments*

      Here comes the attachment.
      ------------=_1334231022-8218-1--

      ------------=_1334231022-8218-0--
```

If I view the email within [The Bat](http://www.ritlabs.com/en/products/thebat/), the plain version and the html version are displayed correctly. Within Mozilla Thunderbird 11.0.1 the plain version won't displayed but a reduced html version.

Do I have an error in my logic or does Thunderbird just failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `$fancy`, add everything to `$msg`.

The [Content-Transfer-Encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6) header is better `base64` or `quoted-printable`. It is more foolproof.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Comment: [RFC 1521](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1521) is obsolete. In the future, use the IETF Web site to look up RFC texts; near the top, the related RFCs are shown.